# What is the identity of "ndim, shape, size, ..etc" of ndarray in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm quite new at Python.

After using Matlab for many many years, recently, I started studying numpy/scipy

It seems like the most basic element of numpy seems to be `ndarray`.
In ndarray, there are following attributes:

- `ndarray.ndim`
- `ndarray.shape`
- `ndarray.size`
- ...etc

I'm quite familiar with C++/JAVA classes, but I'm a novice at Python OOP.

---

Q1: My first question is what is the identity of the above attributes?

At first, I assumed that the above attribute might be  public member variables. But soon, I found that `a.ndim = 10` doesn't work (assuming `a` is an object of `ndarray`) So, it seems it is not a public member variable.

Next, I guessed that they might be public methods similar to getter methods in C++. However, when I tried `a.nidm()` with a parenthesis, it doesn't work. So, it seems that it is not a public method.

The other possibility might be that they are private member variables, but  but print `a.ndim` works, so they cannot be private data members.

So, I cannot figure out what is the true identity of the above attributes.

---

Q2. Where I can find the Python code implementation of `ndarray`? Since I installed numpy/scipy on my local PC, I guess there might be some ways to look at the source code, then I think everything might be clear.

Could you give some advice on this?

Comment: For the first part of your question you would do well to read the ['basics' section in the official numpy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.html). Regarding the second part, `numpy.ndarray` is mainly implemented in C rather than Python for performance reasons. You can find most of the C code relating to `ndarray` in the numpy GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray).

Comment: On a side note, you can set `ndarray.shape`, it just has to be a viable shape, otherwise an error will be raised.

Answer (score 5):

`numpy` is implemented as a mix of `C` code and `Python` code.  The source is available for browsing on `github`, and can be downloaded as a `git` repository.  But digging your way into the `C` source takes some work.  A lot of the files are marked as `.c.src`, which means they pass through one or more layers of perprocessing before compiling.

And Python is written in a mix of C and Python as well.  So don't try to force things into C++ terms.

It's probably better to draw on your MATLAB experience, with adjustments to allow for Python.  And `numpy` has a number of quirks that go beyond Python.  It is using Python syntax, but because it has its own C code, it isn't simply a Python class.

I use `Ipython` as my usual working environment.  With that I can use `foo?` to see the documentation for `foo` (same as the Python `help(foo)`, and `foo??` to see the code - if it is writen in Python (like the MATLAB/Octave `type(foo)`)

Python objects have attributes, and methods.  Also `properties` which look like attributes, but actually use methods to get/set.  Usually you don't need to be aware of the difference between attributes and properties.

```
 x.ndim   # as noted, has a get, but no set; see also np.ndim(x)
 x.shape   # has a get, but can also be set; see also np.shape(x)
```

`x.<tab>` in Ipython shows me all the completions for a `ndarray`.  There are 4*18.  Some are methods, some attributes.  `x._<tab>` shows a bunch more that start with `__`.  These are 'private' - not meant for public consumption, but that's just semantics.  You can look at them and use them if needed.

Off hand `x.shape` is the only `ndarray` property that I set, and even with that I usually use `reshape(...)` instead.  Read their docs to see the difference.  `ndim` is the number of dimensions, and it doesn't make sense to change that directly.  It is `len(x.shape)`; change the shape to change `ndim`.  Likewise `x.size` shouldn't be something you change directly.

Some of these properties are accessible via functions.  `np.shape(x) == x.shape`, similar to MATLAB `size(x)`.  (MATLAB doesn't have `.` attribute syntax).

`x.__array_interface__` is a handy property, that gives a dictionary with a number of the attributes

```
In [391]: x.__array_interface__
Out[391]: 
{'descr': [('', '<f8')],
 'version': 3,
 'shape': (50,),
 'typestr': '<f8',
 'strides': None,
 'data': (165646680, False)}
```

The docs for `ndarray(shape, dtype=float, buffer=None, offset=0,
        strides=None, order=None)`, the `__new__` method lists these attributes:

```
`Attributes
----------
T : ndarray
    Transpose of the array.
data : buffer
    The array's elements, in memory.
dtype : dtype object
    Describes the format of the elements in the array.
flags : dict
    Dictionary containing information related to memory use, e.g.,
    'C_CONTIGUOUS', 'OWNDATA', 'WRITEABLE', etc.
flat : numpy.flatiter object
    Flattened version of the array as an iterator.  The iterator
    allows assignments, e.g., ``x.flat = 3`` (See `ndarray.flat` for
    assignment examples; TODO).
imag : ndarray
    Imaginary part of the array.
real : ndarray
    Real part of the array.
size : int
    Number of elements in the array.
itemsize : int
    The memory use of each array element in bytes.
nbytes : int
    The total number of bytes required to store the array data,
    i.e., ``itemsize * size``.
ndim : int
    The array's number of dimensions.
shape : tuple of ints
    Shape of the array.
strides : tuple of ints
    The step-size required to move from one element to the next in
    memory. For example, a contiguous ``(3, 4)`` array of type
    ``int16`` in C-order has strides ``(8, 2)``.  This implies that
    to move from element to element in memory requires jumps of 2 bytes.
    To move from row-to-row, one needs to jump 8 bytes at a time
    (``2 * 4``).
ctypes : ctypes object
    Class containing properties of the array needed for interaction
    with ctypes.
base : ndarray
    If the array is a view into another array, that array is its `base`
    (unless that array is also a view).  The `base` array is where the
    array data is actually stored.
```

All of these should be treated as properties, though I don't think `numpy` actually uses the `property` mechanism.  In general they should be considered to be 'read-only'.   Besides `shape`, I only recall changing `data` (pointer to a data buffer), and `strides`.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your first question, Python has syntactic sugar for [*properties*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property), including fine-grained control of getting, setting, deleting them, as well as restricting any of the above.

So, for example, if you have

```
class Foo(object):
    @property
    def shmip(self):
        return 3
```

then you can write `Foo().shmip` to obtain `3`, but, if that is the class definition, you've disabled setting `Foo().shmip = 4`.

In other words, those are read-only properties.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**

The list you're mentioning is one that contains attributes for a Numpy array.

For example:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
print(type(a))
>><class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Since `a` is an nump.ndarray you're able to use those attributes to find out more about it. (i.e `a.size` will result in 3). To get information about what each one does visit [SciPy's](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) documentation about the attributes.

**Question 2**

You can start [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.html) to get yourself familiar with some of the basics tools of Numpy as well as the [Reference Manual](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/index.html)  assuming you're using v1.9. For information specific to Numpy Array you can go to [Array Objects](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.html).

Their documentation is very extensive and very helpful. Examples are provided throughout the website showing multiple examples.